# Libreoffice calc date format problem

Tags: libreoffice

I'm having problems with LibreOffice calc that look like bugs. How can I discover if somethings a bug/feature/or "issue"?

Example: 
Uploads to google calender in csv format require date/time in EXACTLY this format:

05/17/15,08:30:00 AM
(with leading 0's, h:m:s AM/PM)

I can't get this in LibreOffice calc by setting a custom date format like:
MM/DD/YY (specifying leading zero for months and days 1-9)

Simular for time formats.

The help/documentation isn't quite detailed enough on this exact case but this:

```
"Date and time codes: 
Format             Format Code
Month as 3.        M
Month as 03.       MM
```

Suggests strongly it's a bug.

Comment: Where's exacty the bug - which behaviour do you expect exactly? As far as i see, the only point is adding AM/PM. I can't reproduce a problem concerning leading zeros - this works fine for me with MM for months, for example.

Comment: I can't see why this is a problem, but more info. would be helpful. 1. What is the current cell content/format in calc before you are trying to convert  it to .csv? 2. I assume the date and time are two cells because you have a comma between them. 3. You are starting with .ods file format. More detail about the cell you are starting with and what result you got after saving to .csv is needed.

Comment: Bugs can be checked/reported here. [***Bugzilla Main Page***](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/)..But you want to file a new bug you will need to give a step by step process and the result you think you should get for it to be of any use.

Comment: Also what version of LO are you using?

Comment: Version: 4.2.7.2 Build ID: 420m0(Build:2)   When I did the csv import, I left the type as "Standard" for data like "5/17" (hoping to get a date of 5/17/15 to format as 05/17/15) and couldn't seem to get it changed to Date by entering dates or setting date formats. While this is still confusing, I fixed my problem by changing "standard" type to "date MDY" during the csv import.  I don't understand this cell type feature that seems to remain in the native ods sheet, i.e. how to view the type, change it, etc. and how the format relates to various types.